# Android 11 Api 30 throws java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: android, mobile, permissions, accountmanager, securityexception

i have a little problem with my android authenticator app ... this app is working on android 8.1 without any problem but since Android 11 it is throwing this exception :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: package=android does not belong to uid=1010197
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1072)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.assertPackageMatchesCallingUid(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:2598)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1081)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1072)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivityAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1032)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivityAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1000)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService.startChooseAccountActivityWithAccounts(AccountManagerService.java:4503)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivityAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1000)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService.startChooseAccountActivityWithAccounts(AccountManagerService.java:4503)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService.handleGetAccountsResult(AccountManagerService.java:4512)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService.handleGetAccountsResult(AccountManagerService.java:4512)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService.access$2700(AccountManagerService.java:145)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService.access$2700(AccountManagerService.java:145)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$19.onResult(AccountManagerService.java:4569)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$GetAccountsByTypeAndFeatureSession.sendResult(AccountManagerService.java:4187)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$GetAccountsByTypeAndFeatureSession.sendResult(AccountManagerService.java:4187)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$GetAccountsByTypeAndFeatureSession.checkAccount(AccountManagerService.java:4135)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$GetAccountsByTypeAndFeatureSession.checkAccount(AccountManagerService.java:4135)
    at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$GetAccountsByTypeAndFeatureSession.onResult(AccountManagerService.java:4170)
    at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticatorResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticatorResponse.java:104)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
    at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticatorResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticatorResponse.java:104)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

Here is a short view of my manifest file :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.apps.work.kerberosauthenticator.AuthenticatorStatusActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".DeclineAddingAccountActivity" android:exported="true"/>
<activity android:name=".ServiceTicketActivity" android:exported="true"/>
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:exported="true"/>
```

Targetsdkversion is set to 30, what Activity / Permission needs to add for this startChooseAccountActivity ?

Thanks and Best Regards,

Andre

Comment: Hello! Seems like you need android:exported="true" in your manifest file. I was wondering if you can add the peace of code when this crash is happening.

Comment: android:exported="true" i have set for some activitys without success.